# jquery.validate.js, AJAX, JSP check

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jsp, servlets

I have a `JSP` in which I have 2 `textboxes` : Account number and File number.

These two textboxes values  are required, so I used `jquery.validate.js` to make the checking when user clicks on Submit. What I want is that when user clicks on Submit, an `Ajax` call is made to a `servlet` which queries the database, and if the combination of these two fields is present, the Submit is done, else an error message is printed on the JSP page.
Could you please help me out.

Comment: Could you post your code, what you have tried so far?

Comment: Sure we will help but what and where do we see the code you tried?